# Applying XDT transform based on sibling element value

Tags: xdt-transform, xdt

Given this XML config file:

```
<job-scheduling-data xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData" version="2.0">
  <schedule>
    <trigger>
      <cron>
        <name>Trigger1</name>
        <cron-expression>0 0 1 * * ?</cron-expression>
      </cron>
    </trigger>
    <trigger>
      <cron>
        <name>Trigger2</name>
        <cron-expression>0 0 2 * * ?</cron-expression>
      </cron>
    </trigger>
  </schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

I want to transform `<cron-expression>` value for `Trigger2`.

Using this transform:

```
<job-scheduling-data xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <schedule>
    <trigger>
      <cron>
        <name>Trigger2</name>
        <cron-expression 
          xdt:Transform="Replace" 
          xdt:Locator="XPath(/job-scheduling-data/schedule/trigger/cron[name='Trigger2'])">0 0 3 * * ?</cron-expression>
      </cron>
    </trigger>
  </schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

When the project builds, I see compiler warning:

> No element in the source document matches
>   '/job-scheduling-data/schedule/trigger/cron[name='Trigger2']'.

The XPath query seems correct, but the rule is never applied (hence the compiler warning).

My project is configured to transform on build using TransformXml task in Visual Studio 2015.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PingCrosby [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23232237/) to another question helped solve the problem. The solution is:

```
<job-scheduling-data xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <schedule>
    <trigger>
      <cron xdt:Locator="XPath(//*[local-name()='job-scheduling-data']
                                /*[local-name()='schedule']
                                /*[local-name()='trigger']
                                /*[local-name()='cron']
                                  [*[local-name() = 'name'] = 'Trigger2'])">
        <cron-expression xdt:Transform="Replace">0 0 3 * * ?</cron-expression>
      </cron>
    </trigger>
  </schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```